# Passing dynamic parameters to an annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I am using the following annotation:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(
    propertyName = "connectionParameters", 
    propertyValue = "host=127.0.0.1;port=5445,host=127.0.0.1;port=6600"),
public class TestMDB implements MessageDrivenBean, MessageListener
```

I would like to pull each of these IP addresses and ports and store them in a file `jmsendpoints.properties`... then load them dynamically. Something like this:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(
    propertyName = "connectionParameters", 
    propertyValue = jmsEndpointsProperties.getConnectionParameters()),
public class TestMDB implements MessageDrivenBean, MessageListener
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can have `propertyValue = "jmsendpoints.properties ConnectionParameter"` which you parse dynamically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No.** The annotation processor (the annotation-based framework you're using) needs to implement an approach to handling placeholders.

---

As an example, a similar technique is implemented in [`Spring`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/)

```
@Value("#{systemProperties.dbName}")
```

Here [`Spring`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) implements an approach to *parsing* that particular syntax, which in this case translates to something similar to `System.getProperty("dbName");`

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are not designed to be modifiable at runtime, but you might be able to utilize a bytecode engineering library such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) in order to edit the annotation values dynamically.

Instead, I recommend creating an interface in which you could modify these values.

```
public interface Configurable {
    public String getConnectionParameters();
}

public class TestMDB implements MessageDrivenBean, MessageListener, Configurable {

    public String getConnectionParameters() {
        return jmsEndpointsProperties.getConnectionParameters();
    }

    //...
}
```

You might wish to create a more key-value oriented interface, but that's the general concept of it.