# Passing dynamic parameters to an annotation

Tags: java, annotations, bytecode, javassist, hibernate-filters

I wonder if there is a possiblity to pass dynamically values to an annotation attribute.

I know that annotation are not designed to be modified but I'm using [Hibernate Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html) and condition to be put are not static in my case.

I think that the only solution is to use librairies whose aim is to read and modify byte code such as Javassist or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/index.html) but it would be too much better if there is another solution.

ps: The difficulty in my case is that I should modify annotations (attribute's value) but librairies I mentioned above allow to create not to edit that's why I'm wondering for another solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot. I don't see why you would need to. If you know what value you would've passed to it is, just use it to act on the annotated field.

Comment: What about passing a class argument and creating an instance of it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: the value to put depends on what user checks, initially it's unknown ;-)

Comment: @WillP: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @Issam, my idea was to use a class parameter instead of a value, but i doubt it will integrate with Filters. Something like `@Valid(MyValidator.class)`. Are you on JavaEE or Spring? You may try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568385/passing-dynamic-parameters-to-an-annotation

Comment: @WillP I'm using JEE, and I suppose that what I need does not depend on what I have as Frameworks. In fact, I wonder if I could change the filter's condition dynamically (the condition is the annotation parameter value). The condition will be fixed by users' choices from UI...
ps: sorry for my late reply

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it integrates nicely with your frameworks, but i would like to suggest the following:

- Create an annotation which receives a Class that implements the validation rule
- Create an interface which the annotation can receive
- Create an implementation for the interface which has the logic for your rule
- Add the annotations to your model class
- Create an annotation processor which applies the validation for each annotated field

I wrote the following example in Groovy, but using standard Java libs and idiomatic Java. Warn me if anything is unreadable:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*

// Our Rule interface
interface Rule<T> { boolean isValid(T t) }

// Here is the annotation which can receive a Rule class
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Validation { Class<? extends Rule> value() }

// An implementation of our Rule, in this case, for a Person's name
class NameRule implements Rule<Person> {
  PersonDAO dao = new PersonDAO()
  boolean isValid(Person person) {
    Integer mode = dao.getNameValidationMode()
    if (mode == 1) { // Don't hardcode numbers; use enums
      return person.name ==~ "[A-Z]{1}[a-z ]{2,25}" // regex matching
    } else if (mode == 2) {
      return person.name ==~ "[a-zA-Z]{1,25}"
    }
  }
}
```

After these declarations, the usage:

```
// Our model with an annotated field
class Person {
  @Validation(NameRule.class)
  String name
}

// Here we are mocking a database select to get the rule save in the database
// Don't use hardcoded numbers, stick to a enum or anything else
class PersonDAO { Integer getNameValidationMode() { return 1 } }
```

The processing of the annotations:

```
// Here we get each annotation and process it against the object
class AnnotationProcessor {
  String validate(Person person) {
    def annotatedFields = person.class.declaredFields.findAll { it.annotations.size() > 0 }
    for (field in annotatedFields) {
      for (annotation in field.annotations) {
        Rule rule = annotation.value().newInstance()
        if (! rule.isValid(person)) {
          return "Error: name is not valid"
        }
        else {
          return "Valid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And tests:

```
// These two must pass
assert new AnnotationProcessor().validate( 
  new Person(name: "spongebob squarepants") ) == "Error: name is not valid"

assert new AnnotationProcessor().validate( 
  new Person(name: "John doe") ) == "Valid"
```

Also, take a look at [GContracts](https://github.com/andresteingress/gcontracts/wiki), it provides some interesting validation-through-annotations model.

Comment: How do you do this in a compile-time annotation processor where `annotation.value().newInstance()` may not work? Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222612/how-to-create-an-instance-out-of-a-typemirror

Answer (score 0):

Annotation parameters are hard coded constants in the classfile. So the only way to change them is to generate a new classfile.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Hibernate, so I can't suggest the best option in your specific case.

Comment: You said that annotation are hard coded in the classfile. So, is there  a possibility to load classfiles and modify some values ? I do not know if you see what  I mean ?

Comment: Once loaded, classfiles are immutable. You can change them all you want before they are loaded though.