# pass variable as annotation parameter

Tags: java, annotations

I am using annotation in my java program something like this.

```
@annotation("some string")
public void fun(){
...
}
```

Is there any way that i could pass variable instead of "some string" to annotation.

e.g

```
String s="some string"
@annotation(s)
public void fun(){
...
}
```

Comment: What's the context? Where does the information have to come from? You can't use a class or local variable as argument to an annotation.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java) answers your question?

Comment: In short: not, it's not possible. The annotation parameter values should be compile-time constants

Comment: Have you tried this? Were there errors?

Comment: duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568385/passing-dynamic-parameters-to-an-annotation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing dynamic parameters to an annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568385/passing-dynamic-parameters-to-an-annotation)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to give an annotation a changing variable. The value which is passed in to the annotation needs to be known at compile time.

This would work:

```
private final String param = "Param";

@annotation(param)
public void function() {

}
```

However, it must be constant and cannot be changed, e.g. intialized by the constructor. (The value in this case would be known at runtime, not compile time)