# Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'run': Exactly one of the 'cron', 'fixedDelay(String)', or 'fixedRate(String)' attributes is required

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-scheduled

Don't know might be the issue here, just added a standard cron job to my application, it works if it's hardcoded!

**application.properties**

```
qronicle.data-retention.retryCronSchedule = 0 * * * * *
```

**DataRetentionDeliveryMethod**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "\${qronicle.data-retention.retryCronSchedule}")
@Transactional
override fun run() {
    LOGGER.info("Running retry job.")

    val retentionRecords = retentionRepository.findAllByStateAndRetryCountLessThan()
    LOGGER.info("Will attempt to reprocess ${retentionRecords.size} retention records.")
```

**Throws out the following error**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-18 14:02:25.221 ERROR 20 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'retentionRetryJob$qronicle' defined in class path resource [com/netapp/qronicle/config/ApplicationConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'run': Exactly one of the 'cron', 'fixedDelay(String)', or 'fixedRate(String)' attributes is required
```

Worth mentioning, running the application inside IntelliJ seems to work,

```
giving the following log line...
2019-06-18 17:30:35.388  INFO 15642 --- [           main] c.n.q.p.delivery.RetentionRetryJob       : Started retention retry job with schedule: 0 * * * * *.
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing dynamic values to the annotations is not possible in java. You can check this post for your reference.

[Passing dynamic parameters to an annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568385/passing-dynamic-parameters-to-an-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

First try without "\" in @Scheduled like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${qronicle.data-retention.retryCronSchedule}")
```

If this does not work, try add annotation to your class @EnableScheduling.